# css grid height scroll bar

Tags: html, css

I have this css

```
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  display: grid;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid;
  height: calc(100vh - 20px);
}
```

to make a centered box (full screen) but I notice there's a scrollbar, I wonder if the px is correct why the scrollbar is there?

https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-butterfly-yqx5ix

Comment: Your elements height is `(height: 100vh - 20px) + (vertical margin: 10px x2) + (vertical border thickness: 1px x2)`. Which leaves you with: `100vh + 2px`. Instead of calc()-ing the height, it might be worth looking into [box-sizing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)

Comment: @DBS I tried this it won't work? https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-lake-9g0r17

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand **box-sizing** for this.

But before that, add these lines to the css file to fix this.

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

**box-sizing: content-box**
So, the width and the height you apply to an element decides it's content width if the `box-sizing` is set to `content-box` i.e, borders and paddings are not included in that height or width.

For an example:

If you set an element's width to 100 pixels, then the element's content box will be 100 pixels wide, and the width of any border or padding will be added to the final rendered width, making the element wider than 100px. And because this value is default, your App exceeds the height of the browser.

**box-sizing: border-box**

border-box tells the browser to account for any border and padding in the values you specify for an element's width and height. If you set an element's width to 100 pixels, that 100 pixels will include any border or padding you added, and the content box will shrink to absorb that extra width.

Source: [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-snowflake-r9ojn8 does it work? it doesn't seem to work

Comment: Yes indeed! The scrollbar is not there now. [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u48sB.png)

Comment: why is it still scrollable? is it codesandbox issue?